# unable to decrypt .asc file using databricks

Tags: python-3.x, bash, encryption, databricks, azure-databricks

I have 1 .zip.asc file ,inside that 3 txt files are there. I am trying to decrypt the **test.zip.asc**  using below code but not working ,though while using tool it is working fine.

**Databricks code**

```
%sh
#Apply looping for each file in the source folder.
for entry in /dbfs/mnt/acc/Temp/*
do

#Create input variable
input=test.zip.asc
echo $input

#create output variable
output=test.zip
echo=$output


#import private key
gpg --no---batch --import /dbfs/mnt/acc/pgp/PrivateKey.asc

#start decryption
gpg --no--tty --batch --yes --ignore-mdc-error --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase-fd 1 --passphrase-file /dbfs/mnt/acc/pgp/Passphrase.txt --output /dbfs/mnt/acc/out/$output --decrypt /dbfs/mnt/acc/input/$input

done
```

**output I'm getting**

test.zip.asc
test.zip
gpg:no valid openPGP data found.
gpg:Total number proessed:0
gpg:enrypted with RSA key ,ID A48FAF69A4E7B316
gpg:decryption failed : No secret key

Comment: From your outout, the line `gpg:no valid openPGP data found.` indicates that your PrivateKey.asc file is not PGP.  Are you sure it is?  And are you sure you have permissions to access it?

Comment: @Nic3500 yes I have permission ,I have only placed the file. I am able to decrypt file while using tool but not able to do it using code.

Comment: Check the below code:
#Create input variable
input=test.zip.asc
echo $input

#create output variable
output=test.zip
echo=$output


#import private key
gpg --no-tty --batch --import /dbfs/mnt/acc/pgp/PrivateKey.asc

#start decryption
gpg --no-tty --batch --yes --ignore-mdc-error --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase-fd 1 --passphrase-file /dbfs/mnt/acc/pgp/Passphrase.txt --output /dbfs/mnt/acc/out/$output --decrypt /dbfs/mnt/acc/input/$input